# FlexBox Item growFactor is not updating the style if the binding is changing

Tags: sapui5

Here is the plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/XVINtJ1RbNrkaCAFbZti?p=preview

I have a view with a FlexBox with 2 items that span 100% width.

```
      <FlexBox width="100%">
      <items>
        <Button press="onButtonLeftPress" text="{LayoutModel>/left}" width="100%" type="Emphasized" >
          <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="{LayoutModel>/left}" />
          </layoutData>
        </Button>
        <Button press="onButtonRightPress" text="{LayoutModel>/right}" width="100%" type="Reject">
          <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="{LayoutModel>/right}" />
          </layoutData>
        </Button>
      </items>
    </FlexBox>
```

The growFactor of the 2 FlexBox items are bound to a LayoutModel that is initialized in index.html

```
var layoutModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
layoutModel.setData({
  left: 2,
  right: 1
});

ui5Core.setModel(layoutModel, "LayoutModel");
```

By pressing the buttons I update the model properties "left" and "right". The values are updated as you can see but the style for the items is not updated. 
I see that FlexBox is taking into consideration only at initialization the values, but if the value is changed the UI is not updated.

The main idea is that I'm trying to obtain a layout with 2-3 columns that collapse/expand.
Do you have any ideas how to obtain this? or how to solve this FlexBox bug?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call invalidate() on the FlexBox instance inside your handler functions. This will make the FlexBox rerender and everything works as expected. Here is a "One-File" jsbin example: https://jsbin.com/pisadigene/edit?html,output

I did not check the code of the FlexBox but I guess that updating the GrowFactor of a FlexBox item does not trigger a change (i.e. rerendering). I guess it’s just a one-time thing...
However, you should be aware that using invalidate() will trigger a re-rendering for all content inside the FlexBox. So that is not a good idea in case you have a lot of content inside the FlexBox because it can have a negative effect on performance… I am not very sure what you try to achieve but using flexboxes for a complete layout of the app might not be a good idea. Instead you should check the other opportunities you have with SAPUI5, i.e. MatrixLayout etc.

Comment: the content of the expanded view is different than the one on the collapsed view so I don't mind to if the content is re-rendered. MatrixLayout is not available in sap.m as I saw. The posibilities would be FlexBox or Grid

Comment: I see... Well, there is a lot which is not in sap.m and you can or even have to use it, i.e. the JSONModel. You can use anything inside sap.ui.layout, i.e. HorizontalLayout, VerticalLayout,... However, you are correct: I think you should not use MatrixLayout because it is inside sap.ui.commons.layout. Try to avoid mixing sap.ui.commons with sap.m controls. Maybe you can find something in sap.ui.layout, i.e. sap.ui.layout.Grid? Also check the [IconTabBar](https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.IconTabBar/samples), maybe this is what you are looking for...